# css background color same size for all div in a row in responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am using 3 div class under a parent div.
first div has background with arrow icon but that div has no contents.
Second div has contents.
Third div has another background.

Now I am trying to make same background height for first and last div by measiring middle div height. But when I am trying to make it responsive. it's not keeping same height background.
Because in small screen middle div contents getting bigger and following this side background height not increasing. because those div has no contents.

I used height for two sides div to make it same for desktop view.

[image]

```css
.timetable-first-section{
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0px 1px auto;
    float: left;
    }

    .before-first {
      background: url(https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/attachment/1459391/7kdanuewzygiyrn23179/610761-K6hpNbrcwFO5jtHQ/left_border.svg) no-repeat;
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      height: 276px;
      width: 8%;
      float: left;
      background-position: 0px -2px 0px 6px;
      background-position: right 0px top;
      }
     .timetable-row-parent {
      float: left;
      height: 276px;
      width: 81%;
      margin-left: 0px;
      border-left: 1px dashed #d2b454;
      border-right: 1px dashed #d2b454;
      }
    .after-first {
    background: url(https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/attachment/1459414/onaqp4bohrm53axh1epf/610761-LX867urAjQXwUttz/right_border.svg) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 17px;
    float: left;
    height: 276px;
    background-position: -4px 14px;
    background-size: 100% 94%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="timetable-first-section">
    <div class="before-first">

        <div class="time">
            <span>
                14:30~<br> 
                17:00
            </span>
            <p>ttttttt</p>
        </div>

        <span>  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timetable-row-parent">
        all contents here
    </div>
    <div class="after-first">
        <span>  </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clearly the code supplied does **not** demonstrate the issue...perhaps you could fix that?

Comment: you're using relative, local urls for your images, so the snippet doesn't demonstrate the issue. Try to fix that so we can help

Comment: also your HTML doesn't match the stated issue, as the first div is not empty, but has a child with time and thingies.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini I just put sample code and I tried to link that image. can you suggest where I can upload image and display that in snippet?

Comment: @Paulie_D I gave height on my first and last div to make those same. but regarding responsiveness what can i do? can u suggest?

Comment: Does the code you supplied **demonstrate** the problem? If not....add more until it *does*

Comment: @Paulie_D added background images and updated my question. now it's displaying same as my problem. left and right side image responsive problem following middle div.

Comment: why are you expecting both images to measure the same, when one of them has background-size 94% and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... this is SO confusing.. You have inline blocks, mixed with floats, got contents on your first div which doesn't match the described behaviour, then unnecessarily uses SVGs...

Maybe this is what you're trying to do?

```css
.contents{
  width:90%; margin:0 auto; padding:0;
  height:300px;
  background:lightgrey;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow:  
    -8px 0 0 -5px white,
    8px 0 0 -5px white,
    -8px 0 0 0 skyblue,
    8px 0 0 0 skyblue;
 }
 
 .contents:before, .contents:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; 
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 
 .contents:before{
  left:-28px;
  border-right:10px solid skyblue;
}

 .contents:after{
  right:-28px;
  border-left:10px solid skyblue;
}


.contents p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <p>All content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May be I tried wrong policy to do it like yours result. ok I will follow your policy may be it will be ok.

Comment: I have updated my question with image url. now in snippet you can see my exact problem in responsive issue.there i used height to display full image. may be that not good in my code also.

Comment: @LemonKazi still can't see the images